# CentOS 6 64Bit For DNS for my domain

Tags: dns, centos, rewrite, nameserver

Entries in DNS (named) are like

```
www A 1.1.1.1
mail A 2.2.2.2
```

Well I am using wordpress in www.mydomainname.com  now I have www.mydomain.com/?pageid=16 used for blogs

so I want to add a entry in DNS which directly points that full URL (No issues if name changes after redirection)

so as a user type blogs.mydomainname.com it should land on I have www.mydomain.com/?pageid=16

Comment: That has nothing to do with DNS, you'll need to do that in Apache or Ngnix, or some other program that deals with http requests.

Comment: Can you please share an example Well I am using HTTPD server (apache)
Thanks for your reply

Comment: I'll give you a simple example, and a link to where to find more `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: `RewriteRule   ^/$  /?pageid=16  [R]`

Comment: The page you need to look at is this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: my point of interest is 
www.mydomainame.com should work as its working
blogs.mydomainname.com should automatic redirect to pageid=16..

now if I write this rule
<pre>
RewriteRule ^/$ /?pageid=16 [R]
</pre>
it will give issue in www.mydomainname.com also will go to that pageid=16

Comment: No, not at all. This is information that goes into your httpd.conf, or into an .htaccess file. It requires that you have administrative access to your server, and also in this case, requires that you are running apache. If you don't know anything about that, I recommend you read the page I posted, and possibly the rest of the documentation on that site.